# Which approach is preferable for creating a grid - flexbox, css-table or inline-block?

Tags: css, flexbox, css-tables

Which approach is preferable for creating a grid - flexbox, css-table or inline-block?

Or may be each of this technics should be used in specified cases?
If so, in what cases should be they used?

Comment: Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise. I voted to close this. If you want it to be kept open, please make it more specific.

Comment: @LGSon Ok, and would you please explain how novice could understand which of this technics should he use when he is not allowed to ask questions (may be too primitive for professionals)?

Comment: No, not too primitive, simply off-topic at Stackoverflow. More info here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic ... If you ask 10 pro's they will ask you how/what/when/where etc., hence not easily answerable, and highly opinion-based, based on each pro's normal playground

Comment: Well and how could one get known of different pro's opinions and argumentations to make his choice?

Comment: A pro's choice is based on facts, so you need to be much more specific. Start with writing down all the requirements you have, and then go from there and ask questions how to solve, not which is better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

each has benefits and disadvantages.
Flexbox is very useful in many cases, but some browsers still lacks the features.

Tables may sound oldskool, but if you are coding an html mailing, it is still the best way.

I think before starting a project, you should check other projects and search on google what is best for you scope.

Comment: Are CSS tables used for mailing? I mean not classical HTML tables `<table>...</table>` but CSS tables like this: `<div style="display:table">...</div>`

Answer (score 1):

Flexbox is becoming the most popular among web developers these days. Websites have been able to get much more responsive on different screen sizes over the last few years which is why using flexboxes is the most popular at this point. It is finally supported on all of the main browsers and provides a good interface for building anything.

Using inline-blocks is still useful however, in different parts of a website, usually with less elements or only two columns, such as a image or an icon next to a body of text.

Comment: And what about css-tables (display: table) ?

Comment: Sorry for the slow response, display tables are older technology in my opinion. They were used heavily before responsive websites was the main focus. They have some uses but mainly i would stay away from display table for the most part.

Comment: So, in short we could say, that for creating grids the best way is using flexbox and may be inline-blocks in simle cases, right?

Ok, and are there any advantage of using inline-blocks? May be the spead of rendering or special cases or smth else?

Or could we say that we can always use flexboxes and not even think of using other two approaches?

Sertainly if we do not have to support old bowser versions;

Comment: I would say go to flexboxes immediately, and if for some reason you are looking for different functionality, then look to doing it with inline block. If you are doing something with only 2 items, then inline-block is nice, such as what i explained in my answer.

Comment: Thanks for your very informative answer